# Azure Table Storage: questions regarding the structure of objects in a table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a few questions regarding the Windows Azure Table Storage. Unfortunately my trial account expired a few days ago and I cannot test it by myself.

1. How do my plain old clr objects get mapped to the table storage? Is it one object per table row, or gets one object splitted up across multiple table rows?
2. Linq and the Entity Framework are  the only ready-to-use frameworks for Table Storage, right?
3. Regardless of using Entity Framework or linq, do I have to pollute my POCOs with some overhead like an `int id`?
4. I know there are no foreign keys, how does the Enitity Framework keep objects together?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you can do both.
2. You can use Linq, but EF is basically for relational data, so it is not for table storage.
3. Your POCO should map to your table storage and inherit from TableServiceEntity which includes partitionkey and rowkey.
4. It is not pratical to use EF for table storage.